# Python Splinter Get Value From Table (Following-Sibling)

Tags: python, xpath, splinter

Given this code ("sleep" instances used to help display what's going on):

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

with Browser() as browser:
    # Visit URL
    url = "https://mdoe.state.mi.us/moecs/PublicCredentialSearch.aspx"
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtCredentialNumber', 'IF0000000262422')

# Find and click the 'search' button
button = browser.find_by_name('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch')
# Interact with elements
button.first.click()
time.sleep(5)

#Only click the link next to "Professional Teaching Certificate Renewal"
certificate_link = browser.find_by_xpath("//td[. = 'Professional Teaching Certificate Renewal']/following-sibling::td/a") 
certificate_link.first.click()
time.sleep(10)
```

I am now trying to get the values from the table that shows after this code runs. I am not well-versed in xpath commands, but based on the response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47971823/python-splinter-click-link-in-table-conditional/47972457#47972457), I have tried these, to no avail:

```
name = browser.find_by_xpath("//td[. ='Name']/following-sibling::td/a")
name = browser.find_by_xpath("//td[. ='Name']/following-sibling::td/[1]")
name = browser.find_by_xpath("//td[. ='Name']/following-sibling::td/[2]")
```

I tried [2] because I do notice a colon (:) sibling character between "Name" and the cell containing the name. I just want the string value of the name itself (and all other values in the table).

I do notice a different structure (span is used within td instead of just td) in this case (I also tried td span[. ='Name']... but no dice):

**Updated to show more detail**

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <span class="MOECSBold">Name</span>
 </td>
 <td>:</td>
 <td>
     <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lblName" class="MOECSNormal">MICHAEL WILLIAM LANCE  </span>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you try `//td[. ='Name']/following-sibling::td/span` or `//td[. ='Name']/following-sibling::td[2]`?

Comment: I just did, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working:

```
browser.find_by_xpath("//td[span='Name']/following-sibling::td")[1].value
```